# Wildfly 13.0 failing to deploy multiple WARs while deploying from Eclipse, works fine otherwise

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly-13

as the title says, I am trying to deploy two WARs on Wildfly 13.0, but if I try to do that on Eclipse by simply adding the resources, it will fail with the following error:

```
10:16:02,532 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.5.Final
10:16:02,845 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.2.Final
10:16:02,876 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
10:16:02,970 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) starting
10:16:04,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
10:16:04,038 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
10:16:04,038 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.3.3.Final
10:16:04,038 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment AmexDAPWebServices.war
10:16:04,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment amexsbswebapp.war
10:16:05,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found AmexDAPWebServices.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called AmexDAPWebServices.war.dodeploy
10:16:05,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found amexsbswebapp.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called amexsbswebapp.war.dodeploy
10:16:05,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:16:05,811 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.6.3.Final
10:16:05,811 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.3.Final
10:16:05,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYEE0119: The system property 'ee8.preview.mode' is NOT set to 'true'. For provided EE 8 APIs where the EE 8 version of the API differs from what is supported in EE 7, the EE 7 variant of the API will be used. Support for this setting will be removed once all EE 8 APIs are provided and certified.
10:16:05,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:16:05,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
10:16:05,858 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
10:16:05,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:16:05,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.5.1.Final
10:16:05,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
10:16:05,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
10:16:05,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.9.Final)
10:16:05,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
10:16:05,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
10:16:05,936 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.9.Final starting
10:16:05,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
10:16:05,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
10:16:05,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:16:06,061 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\v.cappellini\wildfly-13.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
10:16:06,186 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
10:16:06,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
10:16:06,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
10:16:06,233 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.7.Final
10:16:06,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
10:16:06,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
10:16:06,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
10:16:06,311 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
10:16:06,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
10:16:06,342 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\v.cappellini\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
10:16:06,342 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\v.cappellini\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
10:16:06,358 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "amexsbswebapp.war" (runtime-name: "amexsbswebapp.war")
10:16:06,358 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "AmexDAPWebServices.war" (runtime-name: "AmexDAPWebServices.war")
10:16:06,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:16:06,795 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
10:16:06,863 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.4.jbossorg-1) 
10:16:14,642 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0081: The deployment amexsbswebapp.war will not be distributable because this feature is disabled in web-fragment.xml of the module apiee-core-1.0.1.jar.
10:16:15,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for JPAAmex
10:16:15,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for JPAAmex
10:16:17,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'amexsbswebapp.war#JPAAmex'
10:16:17,347 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: JPAAmex
    ...]
10:16:17,363 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."amexsbswebapp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."amexsbswebapp.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "amexsbswebapp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class olsa.cerved.corporate.SBSTemplateManager with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.amexsbswebapp.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/olsa/amex/services/parameters/ApplicationTemplateParameters
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.olsa.amex.services.parameters.ApplicationTemplateParameters from [Module "deployment.amexsbswebapp.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 18 more

10:16:17,410 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.14.Final}
10:16:17,410 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:16:17,410 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
10:16:17,441 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.2.Final}
10:16:18,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'AmexDAPWebServices.war#JPAAmex'
10:16:18,410 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: JPAAmex
    ...]
10:16:18,412 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."AmexDAPWebServices.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."AmexDAPWebServices.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "AmexDAPWebServices.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class amexdap.webservices.LoginUserServletDB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.AmexDAPWebServices.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/olsa/amex/services/LoginService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.olsa.amex.services.LoginService from [Module "deployment.AmexDAPWebServices.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 18 more

10:16:19,069 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "AmexDAPWebServices.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"AmexDAPWebServices.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"AmexDAPWebServices.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class amexdap.webservices.LoginUserServletDB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.AmexDAPWebServices.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/olsa/amex/services/LoginService;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.olsa.amex.services.LoginService from [Module \"deployment.AmexDAPWebServices.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
10:16:19,069 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "amexsbswebapp.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"amexsbswebapp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"amexsbswebapp.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class olsa.cerved.corporate.SBSTemplateManager with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.amexsbswebapp.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/olsa/amex/services/parameters/ApplicationTemplateParameters
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.olsa.amex.services.parameters.ApplicationTemplateParameters from [Module \"deployment.amexsbswebapp.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
10:16:19,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "amexsbswebapp.war" (runtime-name : "amexsbswebapp.war")
10:16:19,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "AmexDAPWebServices.war" (runtime-name : "AmexDAPWebServices.war")
10:16:19,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."AmexDAPWebServices.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "AmexDAPWebServices.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."amexsbswebapp.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "amexsbswebapp.war"

10:16:19,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
10:16:19,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
10:16:19,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:16:19,131 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 16942ms - Started 318 of 541 services (2 services failed or
missing dependencies, 312 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

BUT if I build the WARS with Maven, then paste the WARs manually in the

> {JBOSS_HOME}\standalone\deployments

folder, the WARs will deploy without any problem.
Is there a way to solve this issue? It would save a lot time for me to deploy from Eclipse in order to test/fix issues with the code faster.

EDIT:

How my projects are currently structured:

```
 -Amexwebappsbs (FrontEnd with Angularjs, works fine)
 -AmexDAPWebServices (Backend with servlets and stuff)
      |
      |
      --- AmexDAPLib-1.0(another project with services like db queries with JPA)
            |
            |
            ---- JPAAmex (JPA project with persistence.xml file)
```

Comment: Could you pleas check  scope for dependency of LoginService. It should not be provided or test.

Comment: I'm gonna add the hierarchy of my WAR in the question.

Comment: I tried changing in my pom.xml for AmexDAPWebServices the scope of the AmexDAPLib dependency, but to no avail(I tried test/provided/compile/etc...)

Comment: As I said in the post, if I build my project completely with Maven, I can deploy with no problems at all, it's just when I deploy from Eclipse that everything stops working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution, in order to not "explode" your jars inside the WAR, you need to right click on your project ---> Maven ---> Disable Workspace Resolution.
This solved my problem, I can now deploy without any problem from Eclipse!

Comment: But your changes in the deps will not be available. WildFly *is* able to deal with this exploded format.

Comment: It's not able to deal with exploded JARs nested inside a project, I checked multiple sources like JBOSS forums, Wildfly is able to deal only with exploded WARs.

Comment: I am using it this way since WildFly 8. (And I expect many others using wtp will do). Thus I suspect your setup is somehow broken. But I hope your solution fits your needs.

Comment: This is the issue I am talking about https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-22157?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

From times to times "publishing to Server" from within Eclipse in combination with a non-eclipse-native build-system (here maven) makes some problems.

I would check the following things:

- project settings > Project Facets (Dynamic Web Module)
- project settings > Deployment Assembly
- published files within the deployment folder of your wildfly (sometimes eclipse only deploys .java-files or leaves out some project-dependencies)

If you observe something wrong you may

1. delete project(s) in eclipse (keep files)
2. delete .project, .settings, .classpath files and folders
3. (re)import "existing maven project" in eclipse
4. deploy it to the server (delete at first, then clean and the deploy)
5. finally run wildfly again

Good luck!

P.S. Check your build settings. Sometimes people temporarily deactivate auto-build and miss to build manually.

Comment: I already checked all the settings, and the war generated from Eclipse(which is an exploded war btw) contains all the jars, the only difference from a Maven builded WAR is that the two jars AmexDAPLib and JPAAmex are "exploded" and not compressed like the other libs.

Comment: Yep, that's the way, Eclipse does deployment. But have you checked that the exploded jars contain class files, esp. the class file for the class com.olsa.amex.services.LoginService?

Comment: Just checked right now, they're in the exploded jar in : AmexDAPLib-1.0.jar\WEB-INF\classes\

Comment: And yes, the jar is in the WEB-INF\lib directory of the WAR

Comment: Ok. That seems ok. Another difference may be the execution environment. I suggest you are starting the standalone either with the standalone.bat/.sh or from eclipse. You might compare the settings and the jre you are using.

Comment: You might figure out if the error comes from this difference when you start the wildfly using the Eclipse deployment and the standalone-script or vice versa with a "maven-built" war, but executing from Eclipse.

Comment: I noticed now that from Eclipse I get errors from the WAR:

https://imgur.com/a/Y9NJh8T

Comment: From what I am reading around the internet(mostly JBOSS forums), I have confirmation now that JBOSS does indeed support exploded WARS, but does not support exploded JARS, so until I figure out how to make sure the JARS are not exploded, I can't really make it work without a full build with Maven